# How to execute variables in mysql through php

Tags: php, mysql

i have a query that has variables set to zero, but when executed gives an error, Please how can I execute a query with a variable through php

This is what i have tried but doesnt work

```
$query="
    SET @rnk=0; SET @rank=0; SET @curtotalScore=0;
    SELECT 
        (@rnk:=@rnk+1) rnk,
        (@rank:=IF(@curtotalScore=totalScore,@rank,@rnk)) rank,
        (@curtotalScore:=totalScore) newtotalScore
    FROM
        Table";
```

Comment: You have more than one query. Have you used mysqli::multi_query() or something like this?

Comment: If not clear from the previous comment, how you do this depends on the PHP MySQL API you are using. If using `mysql_query()` (which is deprecated and should not be used), you need to separate each of these 4 statements and run them individually with `mysql_query()`. MySQLi supports `multi_query()`, and with PDO, separately.